# Create log file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, logging, scripting

My PowerShell knowledge is somewhat limited, so I'm hoping one of you gurus can help me on this.

The code below is designed to take files from one directory, copy it to another and rename to the machine name and date it was created, and then remove the files from the original directory.

Once complete, it shows a popup to confirm.

I'd like to have a log file created to show:

- Timestamp
- File copied (original name)
- What it was renamed to
- Whether it was successful or not

```
$SourceFolder = "C:\Users\SourceDirectory"
$Destinationfolder = "\\NetworkLocation\DestDirectory"
$Machinename = "$env:computername"
$Date = $(Get-Date).ToString('yy-MM-dd-hh-mm-tt')

$filesToCopy = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File

foreach ($file in $filesToCopy) {
    $Fulldestinationfolder = Join-Path -Path $Destinationfolder  -ChildPath "$machinename-$date"
    
    # Create the new destination folder if it doesn't exist
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Fulldestinationfolder -Force

    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName  -Destination $Fulldestinationfolder
} 

Remove-Item "C:\Users\SourceDirectory\backups\*.*"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$output = $wshell.popup("File Complete")
```

The ps1 works as it is, and we have it packages in a .exe file for the specific use-case. Great for them, but not if something goes wrong.

I've tried creating a $LogFile variable with the location, and tinkered to append the output of the 'foreach' function to that file. Although the file gets created, nothing is written to it. I also suspect I need to define somewhere the information I want written, but not sure on where's best placed to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unattended tasks I often use

```
Start-Transcript -Path "DesiredFilePath.txt"
```

It will take everything you'd usually see in your command window and writes it into this .txt file. So, it will show you e.g. error messages.
You could also create a new string with all the desired information like Timestamp, original file name etc. and then put it in a variable like $NewString and let it write into the command window. It should appear in your .txt file as well.

```
Write-Output "$NewString"
```

To stop the transcript again, simply use

```
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! It's a clean log that shows everything I might need, very simple and straight forward. Thank you for the input :)